# Error for clone project

Tags: git, ubuntu-14.04

I have this error for clone my project.
This is the first clone on this server

> serverpilot@instance-1:~/apps/website/public$ git clone --mirror
>   git@bitbucket.org:iadevelopersusa/projectteam.git 
>  Cloning into
>   bare repository 'projectteam.git'... remote: Counting objects: 6783,
>   done. remote: Compressing objects: 100% (5694/5694), done.
> error:
>   in tree 1e22faed93a55ed28dfbb07d08ee096baef82294: entry index.php has
>   bad mode 000000 
> fatal: Not all child objects of
>   1e22faed93a55ed28dfbb07d08ee096baef82294 are reachable

Comment: Seems like a broken repo...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error message comes from [fsck.c#L319](https://github.com/git/git/blob/c2c5f6b1e479f2c38e0e01345350620944e3527f/fsck.c#L319) introduced for [git 1.5.2.2 in June 2007](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e2ac7cb5fbcf1407003aa07cdcd14141527ea2e3)

> Don't assume tree entries that are not dirs are blobs

You need to contact the BitBucket support in order to request for a [`git fsck`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fsck) on the bare remote repo hosted by BitBucket, and see if they can fix or clean said repo.